# Libgdx support with gradle in android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

I have just started game development in android and for which i choose Libgdx framework, i downloaded gdx-setup.jar file and setup inside android studio. when i opened the libgdx project in android studio, it does not show any 'res' folder, layout, etc. means nothing about gradle (drag & drop). Is there any way so that i could get the gradle (drag and drop) dependency management with Libgdx in android studio..

I searched over the net, but could not get any understandable solution regarding this.

Thanks for your time

Comment: What do you mean by gradle drag & drop?

Comment: @desertkun - like we have in android studio, we drag the textboxes, buttons, labels, etc over the activity and the xml is getting generated just aside within..

Comment: ...that's the UI toolkit and it has nothing to do with Gradle. And no, there isn't one for LibGDX's Scene2D-UI.

Answer (score 1):

LibGDX and Android is not the same thing. LibGDX uses different ways to present ui's which are cross platform.
I've seen some 3rd party software for visually generating scene2D stuff but have never tried it myself.

However, what you are describing is android specific stuff that has nothing to do with LibGDX, so you won't find it.

If you want to get into LibGDX look into [this wiki page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d).

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for a tool where you can create an UI via Drag and Drop you can use Overlap2D. It is an editor for Scene2d which is used by libGDX